# Django template tags in HTML

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to point an image source to a filepath tag I have specified in my `views.py`, but for some reason it won't load in the project index file, but will in the specific projects pages. And all my other tags on the same page work, so I'm unsure what I am doing wrong?

```
<img src="{{ filepath }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Project Image">
```

Appears in the page as `<img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="Project Image">` which shows the alt text.

**views.py**

```
def project_details(request, slug):
    project = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    filepath = "/static/img/" + project.title + ".png"
    context = {'project': project, 'filepath': filepath}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_details.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you pass it to the template via context? Can you share the whole view funtion?

Comment: I updated the question with the function called @Marco

Comment: Are you sure that `project.title` is a valid string? Which value does filepath have when you debug your view?

Comment: project.title is in the db and works in the card header, so I imagined it would be fine for this too. How would you go about further debugging the view sorry?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. I suspect an invalid `title` or something. You should think about that `filepath` anyway as it should be a valid URL encoded string or slug etc.

Comment: Do you mean something like {% url filepath %}?

Answer (score 1):

So, for those who encounter the same issue, the solution I found to work was:

```
src="{{"/static/img/"|add:project.title|add:".png"}}"
```

This does require the image to be capitalized however. As the project.title value is, navigate that how you wish.